# How to change the extension of an image after it has been inserted into the XSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, apache-poi

After adding an image to the `XSSFWorkbook`, I am trying to change the extension of the inserted image. However, the [PackagePartName](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/PackagePartName.html) doesn't allow changing of the extension once it is set.

```java
// Getting the workbook
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("testWorkbook.xlsx");
XSSFWorkbook wb = (XSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(in);

InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("/home/test/test1.png");
// Get the contents of an InputStream as a byte array
byte[] imageData = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

// Inserting the image
int pictureIndex = workbook.addPicture(imageData, XSSFWorkbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);

XSSFPictureData xssfPictureData = workbook.getAllPictures().get(pictureIndex);

System.out.println(xssfPictureData.getPackagePart().getPartName().getName()); // /xl/media/image1.png
System.out.println(xssfPictureData.getPackagePart().getPartName().getExtension()); // png

// Looking for something similar to this.
xssfPictureData.getPackagePart().getPartName().setExtension("svg"); // Not supported
```

Is there a way to change the extension of the image?

Comment: Why do you think you need changing that file name? `Excel` itself names those files `image1`, `image2`, ... `imageN` when inserted from its `GUI`. This name has nothing to do with the shape name in the drawing which is visible in `GUI`.

Comment: Actually this is related to [adding SVG images to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67666241/how-to-add-svg-image-to-xssfworkbook). I have successfully added the `SVG` images to the `XSSFWorkbook`. However, it is being inserted as a `PNG` image,i.e, `image1.png`. I actually need to change the extension of the `image1.png` to `image1.svg`.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. I have edited the question from changing names to changing extension.

Comment: Currently you cannot add `*.svg` images to an `Excel` workbook. This is not supported until now. And no, it is not only about the file name extension. The file names in `/xl/media` also are referenced in relationships (`*.rel` files). So when name is changed all those relationships also needs to be changed. This is not a simple task.

Comment: I totally understand that. Is there anyway I can access the `XML` of `drawings.xml`? Or any other lead that might be helpful.

Comment: Changing the `drawings.xml` the is the simplest task then (`XSSFDrawing.getCTDrawing`). Have a look at https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_0_0/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.java?view=markup#l530 for how `XSSFWorkbook.addPicture` works. You would need extend `XSSFPictureData` having a new `XSSFRelation.IMAGE_SVG`.